# Qooxdoo source version works fine but build doesn't

Tags: qooxdoo

My source version of qx application works fine. I decided to deploy it to the server. I get an error:

`undefined is not a function.`

I used beautifier to convert the optimized .js file to a readable format. Then I find out that some of my classnames (Phonebook.EmployeeWindow and others) are undefined. I try use verbose output and see some strange behaviour. Some output is below:

- Generate packages
- Writing script file Z:\home\phonebook_build.ru\www\JS\Phonebook\source\script\Phonebook.e8149a11a476.js
- Generate loader script
- Writing script file Z:\home\phonebook_build.ru\www\JS\Phonebook\source\script\Phonebook.js

The way I see it, the script should generate two files: loader and "Phonebook.e8149a11a476.js". In the target folder there is only one file: Phonebook.js. I cannot find Phonebook.e8149a11a476.js anywhere. Maybe my classes have been generated into Phonebook.e8149a11a476.js, but this file is missing, and that's why all of my classes are undefined? Is this the correct assumption? And if it's right, why doesn't qx generate this extra file?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you want to deploy a source version of your app. Which isn't meant to be
deployed (but for development purposes only), cause it has relative links to
your downloaded qooxdoo SDK. What you should generate is a build version (`./generate.py
build`), which is meant to be deployed, cause it's for example self-contained
and optimized/minified.

Read more about `source-*` and `build` jobs:

- v2.1.1: http://manual.qooxdoo.org/2.1.1/pages/tool/generator/generator_default_jobs.html
- v3.0 (not yet released): http://manual.qooxdoo.org/3.0/pages/tool/generator/default_jobs_actions.html

Answer (score 0):

As for the Phonebook.e8149a11a476.js file:

Such a file is normally created during source generation, and when the Generator says it writes such a file, it should be there in your .../source/script folder. If not, something on your disk is eating your files ;-).

But this is unrelated w.r.t. your problem, as in the source version these hashed files only contain resource information (like dimensions of images etc.), but no class code.